# Error connecting PostgreSQL 9.5 (odbc) as Linked Server to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, odbc

I'm getting an error by connecting a PostgreSQL Database as an Linkd Server on my SQL Server 2012.

First I tried a local connection out of MS Access which worked fine. So I tried to do the same on my SQL Server 2012.

I set up the ODBCx64 Driver from [PostgreSQL ODBC Driver Repo](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/) and the connection test was succesfull https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNEwD.jpg

But if I want to add it as a linked server in my SQL Server Mgmt Studio it fails to connect https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxso9.jpg

Any tips why it won't connect without errors?

I'm using:

- PostgreSQL 9.5
- SQL Server 2012
- Windows Server 2012
- ODBC_X64_Unicode for Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me.

The wizard in the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio isn't helpful, I set up the connection by myself. I've tested it with selects and it works

Here's the code I used:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'NameShownInMSSQLSrvMgmtStudio', 
@srvproduct=N'PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)', 
@provider=N'MSDASQL', 
@provstr=N'Driver=PostgreSQL Unicode(x64);uid=postgres;Server=SERVERNAME;database=DBNAME;pwd=MyPWD;SSLmode=disable;PORT=5432'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
@rmtsrvname=N'postgresql',
@useself=N'True',
@locallogin=NULL,
@rmtuser=YourUser,
@rmtpassword=YourPW
```